# Reference request on computer networks

Tags: computer-networks

I read about correctness of iterative and recursive algorithms.I need a sequence of book recommendations for learning mathematical aspects of computer networks and data communtions such as applications of graph theory and number theory in routing and security and error control respectively.Please provide layerwise recommendation.I am asking this question as I was unable to find a consolidated list.

Number theory is used in parity codes in error control.Graph theory is used in optimal routing.